# Xchat2: Intercept submitted lines from text box before sending to server

Tags: python, scripting, xchat2

I am attempting to write a script in python and was wondering if there is a method to delay a line typed into the textbox/inputbox to enable some processing *before* it is sent to the server.

I would like to utilize python as I have already solved the issue of processing, just not the issue with the interception.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure, but it seems there is no way to do that from a Python script...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not pretty sure, but after seeing the xchat API for python I saw some functions that maybe could help you. Anyway, the best you can do is check out the documentacion for yourself here http://xchat.org/docs/xchatpython.html#head-baa362bb6aeeed1851452bd2ecc9253317db1e64.

Good luck!

Comment: It appears that this is not possible.